How to subscribe multiple device token for FCM HTTP v1 API using coldfusion
In ColdFusion, we generated an OAuth token to send notifications. However, due to the limitations of FCM HTTP v1, we cannot send notifications to multiple devices at once. To overcome this, we found a solution: using a TOPIC to subscribe device tokens. We attempted to subscribe multiple tokens using the FCM SDK.
We included all the necessary dependent JAR files for subscribing, but it throws an error.
We are using ColdFusion 2023.
Here’s a simplified version of what we’re trying:
<cfset FirebaseAdmin = createObject("java", "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp") />
<cfset FirebaseMessaging = createObject("java", "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging").getInstance(FirebaseAdmin) />

<cfset registrationTokens = ["token1", "token2", "token3"] />
<cfset topic = "/topics/news" />

<!--- Subscribing multiple tokens to a topic --->
<cfset response = FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic) />

However, we’re getting an error when trying to subscribe the tokens.

What error message are you seeing? Please add that to the post and which line does it happen in?

when we are calling FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic) method in response we are getting HTTP 500 :: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor
We want solution for this.
